# Django, Apache and Sessions

Tags: python, django, apache, session, web

How to ensure that session is not cleared after Apache restart( or stop and start) ?

Because when I upgrade my source code and restart Apache, I refresh the web page and there I have to login again. Session is lost.

Session is stored in Memcache. No idea how and why its cleared. How to preserve the session so that the user need not login after the apache restart?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/?from=olddocs).

> For persistent, cached data, set `SESSION_ENGINE` to "`django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db`". This uses a write-through cache – every write to the cache will also be written to the database. Session reads only use the database if the data is not already in the cache.

Comment: Thank you. Have set "SESSION_ENGINE" to "django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies" ( Cookie based Sessions). Any advantages of cached_db over signed_cookies ?

Comment: In that case, your session data is all stored in the cookie, needs to be encrypted to avoid attacks, and you may encountered issues due to maximum cookie size. On database-based session, the session data is stored in database, and only a session ID is stored in the cookie.

Comment: So on Apache restart cookies stored are flushed out? Can't we preserve session with cookie based sessions?

Comment: In your case (with `SESSION_ENGINE` set as `django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies`), the cookie would be stored in the user's browser, and sent forth and back at every user's request. I don't see any particular link with Apache restart; maybe you're playing with salt, or simply have an issue with your `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` value?

Comment: I have no idea how it's linked. But the session is cleared every time I restart.

I don't think it'll clear the memcache data.